# Using Moodle-Webservice core_course_get_enrolled_courses_by_timeline_classification

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I use the webservice
`core_course_get_enrolled_courses_by_timeline_classification`
my curl looks

```
https://MyMoodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=MyToken&wsfunction=core_course_get_enrolled_courses_by_timeline_classification&moodlewsrestformat=json&classification=inprogress&customfieldname=id&customfieldvalue=7159
```

The User with the id 7159 is enrolled in diffrent courses, but the Webservice gibes as result:

```
{"courses":[],"nextoffset":0}
```

Whats wrong? I hoped that i get as result a list of courses which the user is enrolled in.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

For further readers - it might be in reason that user might selected to show some category of courses, for example - archived courses :)
So, when I had switched to "All courses" all begin to work fine.